How to extract specific arrays from each cell in a given range?
I have a range of cells that each contain multiple arrays

I can extract an array easily, for instance, through =D2.materials
I want to extract and merge all of the "materials" arrays, and I can do that by doing something along the lines of =VSTACK(D2.materials, D3.materials, ..., D13.materials)
This is fine with a small number of cells, but it's going to become impractical as I add more and more. Is there a way to simplify the process?
I've tried to see if things like =VSTACK(D2:D13).materials or even =VSTACK(D2.materials:D13.materials) could do anything, but the answer is no. Eventually I'll need to just put together all the arrays in the D2:D range, and I can't do that manually. I also don't have access to scripts.

Look into REDUCE.

I solved it through
=REDUCE(D2.materials, D2:D13, LAMBDA(a, b, VSTACK(a, b.materials)))

